# Writing Unit Tests for Oauth in spring boot framework

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I aim to write unit test for oauth - check if user name and token was correct.

The search led me to this artical [Faking OAuth SSO](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/faking_oauth_sso/)

For now, I am following strategy #1.

Following is the piece of code for which I need to figure out dependencies they haven't mentioned directly.

```
@Test
public void testGetAuthenticationInfo() throws Exception {
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/token")
            .with(authentication(getOauthTestAuthentication()))
            .sessionAttr("scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext", getOauth2ClientContext()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username").value("bwatkins"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.token").value("my-fun-token"));
}
```

I managed to arrange for webApplicationContext as below -

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
```

For springSecurity() method, I am unable to get the dependency right. Whatever I searched for led me to believe that importing org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.* will get me the method but I am unable to get the pom dependency right.

Question 1: Can anybody help me with getting the dependency right?
Question 2: for such a standard thing as OAuth, isn't there a standard spring boot test package that should just require configuration to test if oauth is working fine or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue earlier as mentioned in the issues of spring-security github. It took some time to figure out the correct version which is 4.0.2.RELEASE

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3861

Adding following in pom.xml fixed the issue.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```